# Durable subscription with Qpid JMS client and RabbitMQ

Tags: jms, rabbitmq, qpid

I have problems creating a durable subscription to a topic in RabbitMQ using the Qpid JMS client.

I tried the following:

```
session.createDurableSubscriber( topic, "name" );
```

but I get a JMSAMQException with the message "Queue bound query failed: Woken up due to class javax.jms.JMSException"

Does anyone know the correct way to set up a durable subscriber using Qpid JMS client connecting to RabbitMQ?

Comment: do you set the correct amqp version during the connection?

Comment: yes... A normal topic subscription is working fine. Only durable subscriptions are causing the problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be a Qpid JMS client bug.

The createDurableSubscriber path is making use of a Qpid specific extension to the AMQP specification which RabbitMQ does not support (specifically exchange.bound).   In order for interoperability, it should be guarding such calls in a similar way to QPID-5224.

I'd suggest reporting this on the Qpid users list and raising a JIRA/submitting a patch.